# Hyper-V ServiceConnectionPoint Missing

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v

I have a Computer Object in AD representing one of our servers running Hyper-V.
While building a script, I suddenly noticed this server was not showing up in my list.

The script uses a custom function that queries AD for Hyper-V Service Connection points, so we can easily add servers without having to change the script.
This is how i first noticed. I went into ADSI and confirmed there, that it was missing under the computer object.
I then went in to Powershell, and again, the service point was missing.
This has not impacted anything besides my script as far as I can see. I can still remotely manage hyper-v on that server etc.

Still, I would rather be on the safe side and fix this.
**Is there any safe/Correct way to fixing this, without drastic actions like reinstalling hyper-V.**
(I Would prefer not having to restart this server if possible, as this means I'll have to migrate some machines etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually added the service connection point using the following method:

```
Right Click the Computer Object > Click New > Object... > Select ServiceConnectionPoint > Value = 'CN=Microsoft Hyper-V' > Ok
```

The name must be exact: 'CN=Microsoft Hyper-V'

Answer (score 0):

Doublecheck the ACL in the newly created object (SCP). Many accessrights are not inherited including $[Computername]. 
I have not done this and the Computer did not restart properly on the next patchday. When it came up again, the SCP was deleted. 
I am not sure yet what is the reason, but maybe one of the Hyper-V processes checks if it can Access the SCP.